# Jenkins docker plugin + commit docker slave, how to push it to a external registry. Image saved on docker host configured in cloud template

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins, docker-registry

I am able to start up a jenkins docker slave. I execute some shell command on the slave, after the build completes the image gets saved and tagged with build id of the job.

However, the image is getting saved into the docker host machine (i.e) the hostname of the machine given on the cloud template (Docker URL).

I want the image to be pushed or saved on a different docker registry.

1. jenkins machine
2. docker host (hosting jenkins slaves)
3. docker registry

I am using machine 1 to pull image from 3. Making changes to the image, on successful build push the image to 3 not to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at running a [Docker Distribution](https://github.com/docker/distribution) private registry server so you can pull and push to it.

Once you get that up and running, you can:

```
docker login https://<URL_OF_PRIVATE_REGISTRY>
docker pull <URL_OF_PRIVATE_REGISTRY>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>
docker tag <LOCAL_IMAGE_NAME> <URL_OF_PRIVATE_REGISTRY>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>
docker push <URL_OF_PRIVATE_REGISTRY>/<IMAGE_NAME>:<IMAGE_TAG>
```